# Tempus Dominus installation for bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-5, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I read the script documentation and I tried to implement the script on my example page but I always have the error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function.

Here my code. Inside my head I put:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Popperjs -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha256-BRqBN7dYgABqtY9Hd4ynE+1slnEw+roEPFzQ7TRRfcg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Tempus Dominus JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@eonasdan/tempus-dominus@6.2.10/dist/js/tempus-dominus.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Tempus Dominus Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@eonasdan/tempus-dominus@6.2.10/dist/css/tempus-dominus.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

then, inside the body:

```
<div class="text-center">
                            <div class="btn-group mx-auto" role="group">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-arrow-left" id="previous-day-btn">
                                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
                                </button>
                                <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-7 text-center">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group log-event" id="datetimepicker1" data-td-target-input="nearest" data-td-target-toggle="nearest">
                                            <input id="datetimepicker1Input" type="text" class="form-control" data-td-target="#datetimepicker1" />
                                            <span class="input-group-text" data-td-target="#datetimepicker1" data-td-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                                <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-arrow-right" id="next-day-btn">
                                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

at the end of the page:

```
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>
<script>
            $(function() {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
</script>
```

something is missing? I checked on the console and all the js are correctly loaded with 200 code.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was a conflict with

```
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

my new head is:

```
<!-- Popperjs -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha256-BRqBN7dYgABqtY9Hd4ynE+1slnEw+roEPFzQ7TRRfcg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- jquery needed for some bootstrap effects-->

    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Tempus Dominus -->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Eonasdan/tempus-dominus@master/dist/js/tempus-dominus.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Eonasdan/tempus-dominus@master/dist/js/jQuery-provider.js"></script>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Eonasdan/tempus-dominus@master/dist/css/tempus-dominus.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

now it works as expected